# Generate number

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, c++, wires, resistor

I wanna make some sketch to generate number to represent sensor value, with range from high (900) to low (670), that number decrease with range between 1-10 and with some delay of switching number with range from 5-15 seconds:

```
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void number(){
      int sensor = 0;                  //sensor variable
      int a = random(0, 10);           //range subtraction sensor value
      int delay = random(5000, 15000); //range delay switching value
      for(sensor = 900; sensor >= 670; sensor -=a){ //iteration sensor value with range 670-900
        Serial.println(sensor);
        delay(delay);}
    }

    void loop() {
    number();
    }
```

with output:

- 900 (delay 7 sec)
- 894 (delay 3 sec)
- 988 (delay 5 sec)
- 979 (delay 9 sec)

The sketch above was work as well, **but i still can't using variable "sensor" result after iteration "for" in void loop**. 
I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: upvote for well presented question ... this is a programming question, so the `c++` tag is valid, but the other 4 tags are not valid ... it is not completely clear what you are asking, but that appears to be because of language difference

Comment: i just wanna generate random number, with range, maybe had another alternative sketch?

Comment: To use the `for()` loop iteration variable after the end of the loop, it has to be defined *outside* of the loop. Defining a variable in the loop is a convenience for when you only need it inside the loop.

Comment: how to upvote? so i need to make variable utside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int sensor = 900;                 //variabel sensor

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
}

int number() {
  int a = random(0, 10);          //range pengurang nilai sensor
  int d = random(500, 1500); //range delay perubahan nilai
  if (sensor < 670) {
    sensor = 900;
  }
  sensor -= a;
  delay(d);
  return sensor;
}

void loop() {
  int val = number();
  Serial.println(val);
}
```

I modified the delay for test.

[randomSeed](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/randomseed/) ensures different random values at every run

EDIT: a not blocking version which returns the same values for random interval:

```
int sensor = 900;                 //variabel sensor
unsigned long nextChangeMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
}

int number() {

  if (millis() < nextChangeMillis)
    return sensor;

  int a = random(0, 10);          //range pengurang nilai sensor
  int d = random(500, 1500); //range delay perubahan nilai
  if (sensor < 670) {
    sensor = 900;
  }
  sensor -= a;
  nextChangeMillis += d;
  return sensor;
}

void loop() {
  int val = number();
  Serial.println(val);
}
```

Comment: @Juraj Why did you kind of copied my answer? Btw, you don't need to return sensor in number(), since it's a global variable anyway.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, your function returns only the last value. the function number() should simulate values returned from a sensor

Comment: @Juraj ... thanks ... I thought that was the intention, but I guess the question was not so clear. Upvoted!

Comment: @UlinnuhaLuthfi (I removed my answer, this answer should answer your question already.

Comment: and when in practical, analog port A0 was used actual sensor, can i switch value from random seed with constant value?

Comment: @UlinnuhaLuthfi, not constant. you would get always the same 'random' sequence

Comment: sorry everyone, i just realize how to upvote

Comment: To "hide" the variable `sensor` you could put it inside `number()` and make it `static`. This way it's clear that no-one is allowed to access it.

Comment: @thebusybee, yes I know. but then I would have to explain it

Comment: thanks a lot guys, that sketch was work well, but i get some problem again, when sketch running, range delay 5 sec-15 sec its way too big, and interrupt all system, is there any alternative ways to replace "delay" function?

Comment: @Juraj, thank you

Comment: you're so fast responed dude, awesome

Comment: @UlinnuhaLuthfi, I realized that a sensor would not block but return the same value so I added the improved version some hours ago before your request